# Column family created with phpcassa is not visible by cqlsh and vice versa

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, phpcassa

I just created Column family by phpcassa , Following is the code

```
$sys = new SystemManager('127.0.0.1');
$sys->create_column_family('demo', 'Users');
$pool = new ConnectionPool('demo', array('localhost'));
$users = new ColumnFamily($pool, 'Users');
$users->insert('user0', array("name" => "joe", "state" => "TX"));
$users->insert('user1', array("name" => "bob", "state" => "CA"));
```

when I use cqlsh and go to demo keyspace I am not able to select any record from it, it straightly tell me

```
cqlsh:demo> select * from Users;
Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily users
cqlsh:demo> select * from users;
Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily users
```

Also reverse case, when I am making any table in cqlsh using CREATE TABLE syntax phpcassa not able to find it and throw NOTFOUND exeception.

Comment: I realize that it can be a problem of my cql create table is following CQL 3.0 and might be phpcassa not able to recognize that. I realize this when I am using cassandra-cli I am seeing kind of warning that cql 3.0 version table will omit due to some known issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use doublequotes to force case sensitivity from cqlsh:

> select * from "Users";

Better: just leave it lowercase.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now how case is working. But still my cql 3.0 table not visible to phpcassa, is that confirmed version related problem?

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out, it is version issue table created with CQL version 3.0 is not visible to phpcassa when I created table with CQL 2.0 it is coming in phpcassa without any problem.